# Check if the user input ending with alphabet "F" is a number

Tags: java, apache-commons-lang

I need to check if the user input is a string or a number.

I use the below statement for the purpose,

```
Double.parseDouble(string);
```

It works in most of the scenarios, but fails when the input entered by the user is like
**123F**

This should be considered as a string however the above case considers it as a number. I even tried using

```
 NumberUtils.isNumber(string);
```

but still the behaviour is same.

I tried the following regex pattern which works

```
"-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?"
```

However is there any other alternate api for the same.

Comment: It's parsing things that look like hex. What sort of inputs do you expect? Are non-integers allowed? Scientific notation?

Comment: @thegrinner: Non integers and scientific notations are not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the rather complicated regular expression that is listed in the documentation for [Double.valueOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29).  If you need to be more restrictive for your application, you will need to write your own regex.  As others pointed out, using Double.parseDouble allows many things, including `Infinity`.

Answer (score 0):

From the [doc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.html#isNumber%28java.lang.String%29)

> Valid numbers include hexadecimal marked with the 0x qualifier,
>   scientific notation and numbers marked with a type qualifier (e.g.
>   123L).

So the `123F` seems to be detected as a hex number.

You can use `NumberUtils.isDigits(String s)` method instead

it checks whether the String contains only digit characters.

So your working code can be look like

```
boolean b = NumberUtils.isDigits(string);
if(!b)
  // then all are digits
```

Comment: Are you referring to  NumberUtils.isDigits(String s) method

Comment: what if the user input is 123.5 I think the NumberUtils.isDigits method will not recognize this as a number

Answer (score 0):

If I was going to support floating point numbers with an F suffix, I'd do it like this:

```
if (str.endsWith("F") || str.endsWith("f")) {
   num = Double.parseDouble(str.substring(0, str.length() - 1));
} else {
   num = Double.parseDouble(str);
}
```

However, I'd recommend that you don't allow this.

The "f" suffix is not a standard mathematical / scientific form. It only has a well defined meaning in certain programming languages ... as numeric *literal* in the *source code* of a program.  In that context, it denotes a floating point number *with an IEE single precision representation*.  (And you are trying to treat it as a `double`!)

The best way to avoid this potential confusion (for a small subset programmers who don't grok the difference between a number and a numeric literal) is to simply treat it as bad input.

---

> However is there any other alternate api for the same.

AFAIK, no.  Mainly because the format doesn't really make sense.